# 'Blowback' with 'much'

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, collocation, uncountable-nouns

Jawad Sukhanyar & Rod Nordland, *In Prison Release, Signs of Karzai’s Rift With U.S.* ([NYT](http://mobile.nytimes.com/2014/02/14/world/asia/afghanistan-releases-prisoners-over-us-objections.html)):

> The amount of people advocating for a long-term relationship with Afghanistan is pretty small in Congress,” Mr. Graham said in an interview on Thursday. “No politician in America is going to get much **blowback** for just pulling out of Afghanistan. [emphasis added]

*Blowback* is not a mass noun *per se*. Is the use of ***much blowback*** grammatical?

Comment: It can't be a mass noun? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @petershor: http://mobile.nytimes.com/2014/02/14/world/asia/afghanistan-releases-prisoners-over-us-objections.html

Comment: In an engineering sense you may speak of "a" blowback, but in a PR sense it's just like "response" or "resistance" or "flak".

Comment: That's not what I was asking; I was asking why you think it can't be a mass noun. The [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/blowback) says it can be a mass noun, and the N.Y. Times is clearly treating it as one.

Comment: @PeterShor The OED and ODE don't have it as such. Although your link shows both mass and countable, I couldn't find it in those other dictionaries. Not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Language changes; my guess is that the use of *blowback* as a mass noun is a fairly recent development, and it hasn't gotten into those dictionaries yet.

Answer (score 1):

Blowback in this context, could be replaced with the word "static".  And, you would happily accept "much static."  (Or perhaps you wouldn't, but I would.)

It is an example of appropriating a word from another field of study, but changing its connotation.  Once this occurs, all of the rules of engagement are out the window.  (See, I just appropriated a military term, and turned it on its ear...)

So, I would say that in this usage blowback is in fact a mass noun.  And, I'm basing this entirely upon the connotation that was determined by common usage.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure ***all** of the rules of engagement* can be so freely ridden roughshod over. That last sentence was probably pushing it a bit, but it seems to me *turning the rules of engagement on its ear* (or *on their ears?!*) would definitely be over the top (practically a violation of the Geneva Convention, not just a breach of some particular army's RoE! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers We Americans have a long and proud history of doing what we damned well please with regard to foreign policy.  And, a small amount of blowback over the usage of the term blowback won't stop us!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the OP interprets the word *blowback* and its supposed usage. I didn't see anything odd at first reading of the quotation cited.

In politics, the term is supposed to suggest 'repercussions,' or sort of.

**[blowback](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blowback)**

> **2** *chiefly US* the unintended adverse results of a political action or situation:
>   *this is the **blowback** from all those aggressive public health campaigns*

*meta*: So, where's the problem? Maybe I'm missing something here?

And Oh, a bit of [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Blowback) may also help: 'flames in enclosed spaces (firearms, furnaces, etc.).'

*Usage*:
Holzner & Holzner, [*Transparency in Global Change*](http://books.google.com/books?id=TJHHTq553SkC&pg=PA5&dq=%22much%20blowback%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fw4DU7PuGeztiAeHw4C4BQ&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA)

> If we're so good, why do we inspire such hatred abroad? What have we done to bring so **much "blowback"** upon ourselves?

Peschek, [*The Politics of Empire*](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=zZaOp0D7xa4C&pg=PA15&dq=%22more%20blowback%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Cg4DU-2sJ-bmiAfYyoHADQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22more%20blowback%22&f=false)

> "blowback itself can lead to **more blowback**, …